# Depsolving for php-pecl-zip

Tags: yum, php, rpm, zip

I'm having trouble getting rid of my depsolving errors, and I've been left to figure this one out on my own. It all started when I wanted to upgrade from PHP 5.2 to PHP 5.3 (heaven forbid), and I was told that we have all kinds of dependency mess because we have multiple PHP packages, and no one else is using it, so if I wanted it, I'd have to do it myself.

I managed to figure out how to get PHP 5.3 installed, but only by removing all previous versions of PHP and doing a fresh install. Now "my" (someone departed's) code is relying on PHPExcel, which relies on php-pecl-zip, which I apparently don't have. Here's some of what I've tried:

**Install with PECL**

```
# pecl install zip   
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/zip"  
install failed
```

Pretty sure this is because our machines have very strict rules about who they can talk to. So I can't access the package via PECL.

**Install with YUM**

```
# yum install php-pecl-zip
Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package             Arch          Version                 Repository      Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 php-pecl-zip        x86_64        1.8.10-2.el5            epel            47 k
Installing for dependencies:
 php-common          x86_64        5.1.6-24.el5_4.5        updates        152 k
```

Why does it want a PHP version 5.1 when I have 5.3?
Of course, if I let it go, it barfs:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /etc/php.ini from install of php-common-5.1.6-24.el5_4.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-5.3.24-7.x86_64
```

And just to verify:

```
# yum list php
Installed Packages
php.x86_64                          5.3.24-7                           installed
```

Can we get around it? A few attempts follow

```
# yum install php-pecl-zip --skip-broken
Transaction Check Error:
  file /etc/php.ini from install of php-common-5.1.6-24.el5_4.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-5.3.24-7.x86_64
```

Skip broken does nothing

```
# yum install php-pecl-zip --skip-broken --exclude=php-common
php-pecl-zip-1.8.10-2.el5.x86_64 from epel has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-api = 20041225 is needed by package php-pecl-zip-1.8.10-2.el5.x86_64 (epel)
Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    php-pecl-zip-1.8.10-2.el5.x86_64 from epel
```

Excluding the package doesn't help

```
# yum install php-pecl-zip --skip-broken --exclude=php-common --exclude=php-api
php-pecl-zip-1.8.10-2.el5.x86_64 from epel has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-api = 20041225 is needed by package php-pecl-zip-1.8.10-2.el5.x86_64 (epel)

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    php-pecl-zip-1.8.10-2.el5.x86_64 from epel
```

Can we install an underlying dependency?

```
# yum install php-api
Package php-common is obsoleted by lift-php, trying to install lift-php-5.3.24-10.x86_64 instead
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package lift-php.x86_64 0:5.3.24-10 set to be updated
--> Processing Conflict: lift-php conflicts php
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
lift-php-5.3.24-10.x86_64 from COMPANY-codex-released has depsolving problems
  --> lift-php conflicts with php
Error: lift-php conflicts with php
```

This is where the dependency loop starts. You'll notice we have COMPANY-codex-released repos that are in play.

```
# yum install php-api --skip-broken
Package php-common is obsoleted by lift-php, trying to install lift-php-5.3.24-10.x86_64 instead
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package lift-php.x86_64 0:5.3.24-10 set to be updated
--> Processing Conflict: lift-php conflicts php
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
lift-php-5.3.24-10.x86_64 from COMPANY-codex-released has depsolving problems
  --> lift-php conflicts with php

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    lift-php-5.3.24-10.x86_64 from COMPANY-codex-released
```

Exclude lift-php?

```
# yum install php-api --exclude=lift-php
================================================================================
 Package           Arch          Version                   Repository      Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 php-common        x86_64        5.1.6-24.el5_4.5          updates        152 k
```

No.

So I think YUM is in a dependency loop.

I also did some silly stuff installing a new EPEL repo, but then yum couldn't resolve any mirrors, so I had to uninstall it. I'm not sure those were symmetric actions, either.

The first time I did this I also had to do `yum install autoconf`

**Install downloaded file with PEAR**
So I went to http://pecl.php.net/package/zip and got a download, scp'd it up to my machine.

```
# pear install -O /home/produser/zip-1.12.4.tgz 
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20090626/php_zip.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20090626/php_zip.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
96 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-rootZ3jpba/zip-1.12.4
running: /var/tmp/zip/configure
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php/20090626
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for zip archive read/writesupport... yes, shared
checking for the location of libz... no
checking pcre install prefix... no
checking libzip... no
checking for the location of zlib... configure: error: zip support requires ZLIB. Use --with-zlib-dir=<DIR> to specify prefix where ZLIB include and library are located
ERROR: `/var/tmp/zip/configure' failed
```

So those first couple of warnings are actually new. Never seen them before just now. Maybe that's a new lead.

(EDIT: I think this startup error is because I went into `/etc/php.ini` and uncommented `extension=php_zip.dll`. When I comment that line back out, it goes away.)

But zlib is there:

```
# yum install zlib
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Plus
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Package zlib-1.2.3-3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

**EDIT:**

```
# rpm -ql zlib
/usr/lib64/libz.so.1
/usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
/usr/share/doc/zlib-1.2.3
/usr/share/doc/zlib-1.2.3/README

# tar xzf zip-1.12.4.tgz
# cd zip-1.12.4
# phpize
# ./configure --with-zlib-dir=/usr/lib64/libz.so.1
configure: error: Can not find zlib headers under "/usr/lib64/libz.so.1"
# ./configure --with-zlib-dir=/usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
configure: error: Can not find zlib headers under "/usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.3"
# ./configure --with-zlib-dir=/usr/share/doc/zlib-1.2.3 #not that i expect this one to work
configure: error: Can not find zlib headers under "/usr/share/doc/zlib-1.2.3"
# ./configure --with-zlib-dir=/usr/share/doc/zlib-1.2.3/README #not that i expect this one to work
configure: error: Can not find zlib headers under "/usr/share/doc/zlib-1.2.3/README"
```

So even though the package manager says that's the location of zlib, and I've started compiling the thing by hand, it still doesn't work.

Reinstall zlib? Seems to execute fine

```
# yum reinstall zlib
Downloading Packages:
zlib-1.2.3-3.x86_64.rpm                                  |  51 kB     00:00     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Finished Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Erasing        : zlib                                                     1/2 
  Installing     : zlib                                                     1/2 

Removed:
  zlib.x86_64 0:1.2.3-3                                                         

Installed:
  zlib.x86_64 0:1.2.3-3                                                         

Complete!
```

**EDIT**
Thanks to these guys: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=692704 I realized I needed to install zlib-devel instead. And just for good measure, to remove one of my warnings, I also did re2c.

```
# yum install zlib-devel
Success

# pear install zip-1.12.4.tgz 
make: *** [php_zip.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed

# yum install re2c
Success

# pear install zip-1.12.4.tgz 
...  
creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/sh /var/tmp/pear-build-root4xHrWH/zip-1.12.4/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/var/tmp/zip -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-root4xHrWH/zip-1.12.4/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-root4xHrWH/zip-1.12.4/main -I/var/tmp/zip -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/var/tmp/zip/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /var/tmp/zip/php_zip.c -o php_zip.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/var/tmp/zip -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-root4xHrWH/zip-1.12.4/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-root4xHrWH/zip-1.12.4/main -I/var/tmp/zip -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/var/tmp/zip/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /var/tmp/zip/php_zip.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/php_zip.o
In file included from /var/tmp/zip/php_zip.c:30:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /var/tmp/zip/php_zip.c:30:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:37: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:38: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:44: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘pcre’
/var/tmp/zip/php_zip.c: In function ‘php_zip_pcre’:
/var/tmp/zip/php_zip.c:672: error: ‘pcre’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/tmp/zip/php_zip.c:672: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/var/tmp/zip/php_zip.c:672: error: for each function it appears in.)
/var/tmp/zip/php_zip.c:672: error: ‘re’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/tmp/zip/php_zip.c:673: error: ‘pcre_extra’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [php_zip.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

**EDIT**
Now these guys (http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/install-zip-extension-using-pear-840755/) say

```
# yum install pcre-devel
```

which doesn't quite work for me, but

```
# yum install COMPANY-pcre-devel
```

works fine

```
# pear install zip-1.12.4.tgz
```

same make error.

**EDIT**
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/red-hat-31/rpm-error-cannot-create-sourcedir-165733/
http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/26/dist/55/size/571124/name/pcre-6.6-2.el5_1.7.src.rpm

```
# yum install rpm-build
# rpmbuild --rebuild pcre-6.6-2.el5_1.7.src.rpm  # manually downloaded this exact version of the rpm
TONS of output, but the tests all passed, so it seems to have worked...
# cd /usr/src/redhat/RPMS/x86_64
# rpm -ivh pcre-devel-6.6-2.7.x86_64.rpm 
# yum list installed | grep pcre
pcre.x86_64                                  6.6-2.7                   installed
pcre-devel.x86_64

                        6.6-2.7                   installed
```

BOOM! Another dependency down.

```
# cd dir/to/manually/uploaded/zip.tgz
# pear install zip-1.12.4.tgz 

Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/20090626/zip.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/zip-1.12.4
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=zip.so" to php.ini
```

Yes sir.

```
# vi /etc/php.ini
add extension=zip.so
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Couldn't access the pecl servers from my server, so download tarball from http://pecl.php.net/package/zip and manually put it on server
- `yum install zlib-devel`
- `yum install pcre-devel` didn't work for me, so I had to go to
  http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/26/dist/55/size/571124/name/pcre-6.6-2.el5_1.7.src.rpm 
  to get the exact RPM version that was listed in my depsolving error.
- `yum install rpm-build`
- `scp pcre-6.6-2.el5_1.7.src.rpm` to my server
- `rpmbuild --rebuild pcre-6.6-2.el5_1.7.src.rpm`
- `cd /usr/src/redhat/RPMS/x86_64`
- `rpm -ivh pcre-devel-6.6-2.7.x86_64.rpm`
- `yum list installed | grep pcre` to see that it worked
- `cd dir/to/manually/uploaded/zip.tgz`
- `pear install zip-1.12.4.tgz`
- `vi /etc/php.ini`
- add `extension=zip.so` to php.ini

Full details and all pages referenced are in the description and edits above.

Comment: this guys answer should be sufficient for most: http://blogs.fsfe.org/samtuke/?p=333